# Multiple Left Join on same table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have two table. 
1st table => member {member_id, name, active}
2nd table => savings {savings_id, member_id, month, year, amount, type, paid}

Member Table

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| member_id | name   | active |
+-----------+--------+--------+
|       105 | Andri  | 1      |
|       106 | Steve  | 1      |
|       110 | Soraya | 1      |
|       111 | Eva    | 1      |
|       112 | Sonia  | 1      |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

Savings Table

```
+------------+-----------+-------+------+--------+------+------+
| savings_id | member_id | month | year | amount | type | paid |
+------------+-----------+-------+------+--------+------+------+
|          1 |       120 |  NULL | NULL | 150000 |    1 | 1    |
|         14 |       105 |     7 | 2014 |  80000 |    2 | 1    |
|         15 |       105 |     7 | 2014 |  25000 |    3 | 1    |
|         16 |       105 |     7 | 2014 |  60000 |    4 | 1    |
|         17 |       105 |     7 | 2014 | 100000 |    5 | 1    |
|         18 |       106 |     7 | 2014 |  80000 |    2 | 1    |
|         19 |       106 |     7 | 2014 |  25000 |    3 | 1    |
|         20 |       106 |     7 | 2014 |  60000 |    4 | 1    |
|         21 |       106 |     7 | 2014 | 100000 |    5 | 1    |
|         31 |       110 |     7 | 2014 |  25000 |    3 | 1    |
|         32 |       110 |     7 | 2014 |  60000 |    4 | 1    |
|         33 |       110 |     7 | 2014 | 100000 |    5 | 1    |
|         34 |       111 |     7 | 2014 |  80000 |    2 | 1    |
|         35 |       111 |     7 | 2014 |  25000 |    3 | 1    |
|         36 |       111 |     7 | 2014 |  60000 |    4 | 1    |
|         37 |       111 |     7 | 2014 | 100000 |    5 | 1    |
|         38 |       112 |     7 | 2014 |  80000 |    2 | 1    |
|         39 |       112 |     7 | 2014 |  25000 |    3 | 1    |
|         40 |       112 |     7 | 2014 |  60000 |    4 | 1    |
|         41 |       112 |     7 | 2014 | 100000 |    5 | 1    |
|         85 |       105 |     7 | 2015 |  80000 |    2 | 1    |
|         86 |       105 |     7 | 2015 |  25000 |    3 | 1    |
|         87 |       105 |     7 | 2015 |  60000 |    4 | 1    |
|         88 |       105 |     7 | 2015 | 100000 |    5 | 1    |
|         89 |       106 |     7 | 2015 |  80000 |    2 |      |
|         90 |       106 |     7 | 2015 |  25000 |    3 |      |
|         91 |       106 |     7 | 2015 |  60000 |    4 |      |
|         92 |       106 |     7 | 2015 | 100000 |    5 |      |
|        101 |       110 |     7 | 2015 |  80000 |    2 |      |
|        102 |       110 |     7 | 2015 |  25000 |    3 |      |
|        103 |       110 |     7 | 2015 |  60000 |    4 |      |
|        104 |       110 |     7 | 2015 | 100000 |    5 |      |
|        105 |       111 |     7 | 2015 |  80000 |    2 | 1    |
|        106 |       111 |     7 | 2015 |  25000 |    3 | 1    |
|        107 |       111 |     7 | 2015 |  60000 |    4 | 1    |
|        108 |       111 |     7 | 2015 | 100000 |    5 | 1    |
|        109 |       112 |     7 | 2015 |  80000 |    2 |      |
|        110 |       112 |     7 | 2015 |  25000 |    3 |      |
|        111 |       112 |     7 | 2015 |  60000 |    4 |      |
|        144 |       110 |     7 | 2014 |  50000 |    1 | 1    |
+------------+-----------+-------+------+--------+------+------+
```

When member make a savings, they could choose 5 type of savings, What i want to do is to make a list of member and all of their saving.

This is mysql query

```
SELECT m.member_id, name, 
SUM(s1.amount) as savings1,
SUM(s2.amount) as savings2,
SUM(s3.amount) as savings3,
SUM(s4.amount) as savings4,
SUM(s5.amount) as savings5
FROM members m
LEFT JOIN savings s1 ON s1.member_id = m.member_id AND s1.type = 1 AND s1.paid = 1
LEFT JOIN savings s2 ON s2.member_id = m.member_id AND s2.type = 2 AND s2.paid = 1
LEFT JOIN savings s3 ON s3.member_id = m.member_id AND s3.type = 3 AND s3.paid = 1
LEFT JOIN savings s4 ON s4.member_id = m.member_id AND s4.type = 4 AND s4.paid = 1
LEFT JOIN savings s5 ON s5.member_id = m.member_id AND s5.type = 5 AND s5.paid = 1
WHERE 
active = 1
GROUP BY m.member_id
```

This is the output

```
+-----------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| member_id | name   | savings1 | savings2 | savings3 | savings4 | savings5 |
+-----------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|       105 | Andri  |     NULL |  1280000 |   400000 |   960000 |  1600000 |
|       106 | Steve  |     NULL |    80000 |    25000 |    60000 |   100000 |
|       110 | Soraya |    50000 |     NULL |    25000 |    60000 |   100000 |
|       111 | Eva    |     NULL |  1280000 |   400000 |   960000 |  1600000 |
|       112 | Sonia  |     NULL |    80000 |    25000 |    60000 |   100000 |
+-----------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

As you can see the calculation is not right, for example savings2 for member 105 it should be 160K. Any suggestion what should be the query for this case.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9eca9/1

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to do an 'GROUP BY m.member_id, s.type' then pivot around member-id?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is you're forming the full join product before summation. So if there is more than one row in more than one of your `savings` tables you will end up with duplication. If you [perform the join without summation](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9eca9/72), you can clearly see what is going on. There are two ways around this.

1. Do all summations in derived tables:

   ```
   SELECT m.member_id, name, 
   s1.amount as savings1,
   s2.amount as savings2,
   ...
   FROM members m
   LEFT JOIN (
       select SUM(amount) as amount, member_id
       from savings
       where type = 1 and paid = 1
       group by member_id
   ) s1 ON s1.member_id = m.member_id
   LEFT JOIN (
       select SUM(amount) as amount, member_id
       from savings
       where type = 2 and paid = 1
       group by member_id
   ) s2 ON s2.member_id = m.member_id
   ...
   WHERE active = 1
   GROUP BY m.member_id
   ```
2. Join once and use a conditional sum:

   ```
   SELECT m.member_id, name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.type = 1 then s.amount ELSE NULL END) as savings1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.type = 2 then s.amount ELSE NULL END) as savings2,
       ...
   LEFT JOIN savings s s2 ON s.member_id = m.member_id AND s.paid = 1
   WHERE active = 1
   GROUP BY m.member_id
   ```

Comment: the power of `SUM` with `CASE` function within really shorten the sql.

Comment: @Charlesliam Yes, and I should mention it only works because it reduces the join to a single table. If you had to sum records across multiple *tables* you couldn't do this because you'd still get a Cartesian product of rows.

Answer (score 5):

You probably do not need multiple left joins and could be done as

```
SELECT 
m.member_id,
m.name,
SUM(case when s.type= 1 then s.amount end) as savings1,
SUM(case when s.type= 2 then s.amount end) as savings2,
SUM(case when s.type= 3 then s.amount end) as savings3,
SUM(case when s.type= 4 then s.amount end) as savings4,
SUM(case when s.type= 5 then s.amount end) as savings5
FROM savings s
join members m on m.member_id = s.member_id
WHERE 
m.active = 1
GROUP BY m.member_id
```

Comment: I think there is some mistake for member_id=106 for saving2 actually it becomes `80000` and your query will return `160000`

Comment: You have to add one more where condition like `s.paid = 1` so get correct result.

Comment: @Sadikhasan, yes adding the condition will have only `80000` but looks like the OP is looking for `savings2 for member 105 it should be 160K`

Comment: When you add condition `s.paid = 1` then also satisfy user requirements and corrected output

Answer (score 2):

this should work

```
SELECT m.member_id, name, 

sum((case when s1.type=1 then s1.amount end)) as savings1,

sum((case when s1.type=2 then s1.amount end)) as savings2,

sum((case when s1.type=3 then s1.amount end)) as savings3,

sum((case when s1.type=4 then s1.amount end)) as savings4,

sum((case when s1.type=5 then s1.amount end)) as savings5

FROM members m

LEFT JOIN savings s1 ON s1.member_id = m.member_id 

WHERE active = 1 and s1.paid=1

GROUP BY m.member_id
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems join has the problem.. U can go above answers all are good option only..

U can use **Pivot Query** also

```
SELECT m.member_id,s1.type,
SUM(s1.amount) as savings
FROM members m
LEFT JOIN savings s1 ON s1.member_id = m.member_id  AND s1.paid = 1
WHERE active = 1
GROUP BY m.member_id ,s1.type
```

// Pivot here

and then try for Pivoting dude.. That also would be nice...