# Is there a way to minimize a SQL query which uses a lot of different conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, format

I have to retrieve and sort data from a server. First of all, the query is too long and I think it could be shorter but I don't know how. Secondly, I get separate tables for each sensor type. But it would be better to have only one table in which there is a column for each sensor type. The difficulty is selecting the distinct top 4 of each sensor and sorting them according to the correct `DateTime`.

```
SELECT TOP(2)
    [clRegId] AS Id, [clRegDateTimestamp] AS DateTime, 
    ([clRegSysNbr] + 1) AS CelNr, 
    ((([clRegValue] - 4860.00)/20.00) - 30.00) AS Value,
    CASE
        WHEN clRegId = 0 THEN ''airTemp''
    END AS Sensor
FROM 
    [Database].[dbo].[registrations] 
WHERE 
    clRegSysNbr = 10 
    AND clRegId = 0 
    AND clRegMain = 3 
    AND clRegConfigId = 3
ORDER BY 
    DateTimestamp DESC


SELECT TOP(2)
    [clRegId] AS Id, [clRegDateTimestamp] AS DateTime, 
    ([clRegSysNbr] + 1) AS CelNr, 
    ([clRegValue] / 40.0) AS Value,
    CASE
        WHEN clRegId = 1 THEN ''product cold''
    END AS Sensor
FROM 
    [Database].[dbo].[registrations] 
WHERE 
    clRegSysNbr = 10 
    AND clRegId = 1 
    AND clRegMain = 3 
    AND clRegConfigId = 3
ORDER BY 
    DateTimestamp DESC
```

This code returns the following separate tables as a result.

First table from the air sensor:

| Id | DateTime | CelNr | Value | Sensor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7/11/2022 13:20:00 | 11 | -0,6 | air |
| 0 | 7/11/2022 13:15:00 | 11 | -0,5 | air |

Second table from the product cold sensor

| Id | DateTime | CelNr | Value | Sensor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7/11/2022 13:20:00 | 11 | -0,8 | product cold |
| 1 | 7/11/2022 13:15:00 | 11 | -0,9 | product cold |

It would be better if it looked like this:

| DateTime | CelNr | air | product cold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/11/2022 13:20:00 | 11 | -0,6 | -0,8 |
| 7/11/2022 13:15:00 | 11 | -0,5 | -0,9 |

Is it possible with SQL to achieve this kind of a combined table as result?

Comment: okay thanks, I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This might be an application for [pivots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 0):

1. This query is by no means 'complex' or 'too long', a lot of reports end up joining multiple tables and having 10-20 columns.
2. Your data is in the same table, so rather than doing two separate statements you can join the table with itself to get the results in one row, like [Multiple Left Join on same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566671/multiple-left-join-on-same-table)

So, your query looks something like:

```
SELECT TOP(2)
    [air.clRegDateTimestamp] AS DateTime, 
    ([air.clRegSysNbr] + 1) AS CelNr, 
    ((([air.clRegValue] - 4860.00)/20.00) - 30.00) AS Air, 
    ([cold.clRegValue] / 40.0) AS Cold        
FROM 
    [Database].[dbo].[registrations] air
LEFT JOIN ( 
            SELECT 
              [clRegDateTimestamp] AS DateTime, 
              ([clRegSysNbr] + 1) AS CelNr,  
              ([clRegValue] / 40.0) AS Value
            FROM [Database].[dbo].[registrations] 
            WHERE  
               clRegSysNbr = 10 
               AND clRegId = 1 -- cold 
               AND clRegMain = 3 
               AND clRegConfigId = 3) cold ON cold.DateTime = air.DateTime 
WHERE 
    clRegSysNbr = 10 
    AND clRegId = 0 -- air 
    AND clRegMain = 3 
    AND clRegConfigId = 3
ORDER BY 
    DateTimestamp DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! However, I think you misunderstood the result. It gives two seperate tables because I execute a select function two times, but all the values are from the same database and table. So for example [air.clRegValue] is not a valid input since "air" is not an existing table.

Comment: @KobeM in the FROM I give your `registrations` the alias `air`. Then I join it with itself, giving that join the alias 'cold' so maybe a bracket is wrong somewhere. Since I don't have your database scheme I can't run it on a SQL server and give you a 100% correct query.

Comment: Ok thank you! I'll try figuring that out.

Comment: @KobeM if you still have issues, dumb down the query to just a single where condition and select. Then build it back up from there. Also take a look at the other SO question I linked for inspiration.